# Swiper: virtual and loop not working together

Tags: swiper.js

codeLink: https://codepen.io/wuyangqin/pen/OJEeQBg

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  height: 400,
  width: 240,
  loop: true,
  autoplay:{
    delay: 2000
  },
  direction: 'vertical',
  slidesPerView: 1,
  centeredSlides: false,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  freeMode: true,
  freeModeSticky: true,
  mousewheel: true,
  slideToClickedSlide: true,
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    type: "fraction"
  },
  scrollbar: {
    el: ".swiper-scrollbar",
    draggable: true,
    dragSize: 40,
  },
  virtual: {
    slides: (function() {
      var slides = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) {
        slides.push(
          '<img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?image=' +
            (i + 1) +
            '"/><p>' +
            (i + 1) +
            "</p>"
        );
      }
      return slides;
    })()
  }
});
```

When I set `Loop:true`, Swiper will stop when it reachEnd;
I tried the issue https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/3070  But still not working

Expect loop and virtual working together

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had autoheight on mine and I removed it and it worked for me.

```
<Swiper
    direction="horizontal"
    slidesPerView={1}
    spaceBetween={30}
    loop
    speed={600}
    className="mySwiper"
    modules={[Virtual]}
    virtual
    style={{ width: '100vw', overflowX: 'hidden' }}
    observer
    observeParents
>
    ...
</Swiper>
```